# I have a painting on silk I'm new to this type of research. Can someone help me identify it plz

Tags: simplified-characters

[image: I need info on this butterfly painting done on silk][silk painting I would like info on starting with the translation I guess I know absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

淩
雲
寫
於
淇
園

...................................................